# SQL Server SSIS Proxy User password length issue

Tags: sql, ssis, password-encryption

Is there a restriction in SQL Server on the length of a service account for SSIS as we are having issues with 127 characters and proxy accounts?

I did find this article about length but this is fairly old. https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/69babc89-a4d6-4d8b-a9b3-d18a24d1c703/conngetproxypassword the articles say reduce it below 100 but our security team need more evidence that it is a Microsoft issue. Anyone else come across this?

Comment: What error did you get?

Comment: unable to start execute of step 1) reason: Error authenicating proxy Domain\ServiceAcct, system error: ConnGetProxyPassword). the step failed.

Comment: Domain/ServiceAcct represent actual AD credentials that i have removed

Comment: I don't know about password length, but I have found this: https://www.sqlteam.com/forums/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=196598 Maybe this can solve your issue.

Comment: Thanks, but still the same issue

Comment: We are seeing the exact same issue and error message on SQL 2016, SP2-CU12. We changed the password length to 98 characters and it now works fine. I recall coming across a different part of SQL where a dialog box silently trims passwords to 100 characters, but in this case were using TSQL to create the Credential, so it wasn't the GUI getting in the way.